# Do I need to develop Twilio Flex from scratch?

Tags: twilio, twilio-flex

I need to implement Twilio Flex at my company, as I understood, Twilio has a built-in React application where they already launch everything for me and host on cloud so I don't need to worry about those type of things.

I'm also in contact with a sales guy that he's saying that I CANNOT use Flex with on that built-in stuff, that I have to develop the application myself and it's mandatory to integrate with some CRM/ERP system.

Is that really the thing? I'll need to develop my own application but using API's from Twilio Flex?

It's just me or this is really that confusing? Could someone really clear me up?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Twilio Flex is an application platform. It gives you an application that works out of the box as a contact centre that you can log agents into and make and receive calls and messages. The front-end of that application is a React application.

We call it an application platform because, while out of the box it is a pretty good contact centre application, you and your business will get the most out of it by customising and implementing features that connect your business into Flex. You can add things to the front-end by creating [Flex plugins](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/developer/plugins) and you can change the behaviour of tasks by updating the rules by editing the [TaskRouter workflows](https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter).

Connecting Flex to your CRM is a useful step to take as it can bring your customer details up when they call in, saving valuable time for the agent and making a better experience for your customer.

So, you don't have to build a whole new application, you can build upon the Flex application. If you want to learn more about building Flex plugins and how flexible the entire application is, I recommend you [check out the Flex tutorials at twiliotraining.com](https://www.twiliotraining.com/).